# Can't store data at section config golang

Tags: go, configuration

i just try to make config with ini file for my first app.

i have config file like this

```
[server]
port         = 1020
environment  = "development"
```

and some code to read the config file.

```
package config

import (
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/gcfg.v1"
)

type ServerConfig struct {
    Port        int    `gcfg:"port"`
    Environment string `gcfg:"environment"`
}

var Server ServerConfig

func InitConfig() {
    err := InitConfigServer()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln("Error init config server : ", err)
        return
    }
}

func InitConfigServer() error {
    err := gcfg.ReadFileInto(&Server, "files/config/config-main.ini")
    return err
}
```

and my main.go will call InitConfig()
when i try to run main.go, i got error

```
Error init config server :  warnings:
can't store data at section "server"
can't store data at section "server"

panic: Error init config server :  warnings:
can't store data at section "server"
can't store data at section "server"
```

can someone explain what actually happened with that errors? i can't clearly understand what wrong with this configuration file.

Thanks

Comment: Per the documentation (https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gcfg.v1): "section corresponds to a struct field in the config struct". You should be reading into a struct with a field `Server` (to take the `server` section). *That* field could be of type `ServerConfig`.

Comment: hi Adrian, i miss that section corresponds to sturuct field.
thank you so much for your explanation. :)

Comment: I didn't want to post as an answer because I've never used that library and didn't test the solution. If it works for you I can repost as an answer.

Comment: i works for me, i just add `MainConfig` struct which has `ServerConfig` struct.
by the way, may i know what library do you usually use for configuration in go?

Comment: I usually use `encoding/json` from the stdlib. JSON is widely-known and easy to work with.

Comment: nice, thanks adrian. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation: "section corresponds to a struct field in the config struct". You should be reading into a struct with a field `Server` (to take the `server` section). That field could be of type `ServerConfig`:

```
type Config struct {
    Server ServerConfig `gcfg:"server"`
}

type ServerConfig struct {
    Port        int    `gcfg:"port"`
    Environment string `gcfg:"environment"`
}

var Config Config

func InitConfig() {
    err := InitConfigServer()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln("Error init config server : ", err)
        return
    }
}

func InitConfigServer() error {
    err := gcfg.ReadFileInto(&Config, "files/config/config-main.ini")
    return err
}
```